# xul arrowpanel handlers

Tags: firefox, xul

I am trying to set popupshowing handler when the popup opens so I can set the margin-right of the ".panel-arrow" dynamically I tried to use XUL Bindings and when the popup shows I will set the margin-right of the ".panel-arrow" dynamically.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<bindings xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/xbl"
         xmlns:xul="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
    <binding id="panelext_panel_arrow_binding" extends="chrome://global/content/bindings/popup.xml#arrowpanel">
        <resources>
            <stylesheet src="chrome://panelext/skin/panel.css"/>
        </resources>
        <handlers>
            <handler event="popupshowing">
                <![CDATA[
                    var consoleService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/consoleservice;1"]
                                                 .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIConsoleService);
                    consoleService.logStringMessage("panelext CHECK");
                ]]>
            </handler>
        </handlers>
    </binding>
</bindings>
```

The resource binding is workings but the handlers isn`t.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just complicated it - the fix is just to add onpopupshowing="EXTENSION_NAME.popupshowing()" to the panel.